# How do I update a web page asynchronously as it processes records

Tags: c#, asynchronous, delegates

I have a .net web app written in c#. From the front end, I click a button that kicks off a long process. The looping logic appears in a lower tier. Every time it loops, I use a delegate to pass it up to the next tier which does the same; using a delegate to pass a message to the UI. If I step through this, it appears to work, but the page isn't actually updated until the very end. I put the literal that needs to be updated in an update panel. I am missing something.

```
public delegate void ProcessedEventHandler(object sender, string msg);
public delegate void LongTimeTaskDelegate();

public class FileApplicationFrameWork
{
    static List<Application> lstApplications = new List<Application>();
    public event ProcessedEventHandler OnRecordProcessed;

    //Constructor
    public FileApplicationFrameWork()
    {
        //Get test data
        TestDataMgt oTestMgt = new TestDataMgt();
        lstApplications = oTestMgt.GetApplicants();
    }

    public void FileApplicationWithoutRegistering()
    {
        try
        {
            int i = 0;

            foreach (Application oApplication in lstApplications)
            {
                if (i < 5)
                {               
                    DoTheWork(oApplication); //This is the long process                
                    OnRecordProcessed(this, "Record Number"); 
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }
    }

    public void DoTheWork(Application oApplication)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
    }
}
```

Then going up to the middle tier...

```
 public delegate void DisplayMessageEventHandler(object sender, string msg);

    public class FileApplicationTests
    {

       public event DisplayMessageEventHandler OnReadyToBeDisplayed;

        public string FileApplication()
        {
            string msg = string.Empty;

            try
            {
                FileApplicationFrameWork filer = new FileApplicationFrameWork();
                filer.OnRecordProcessed += new ProcessedEventHandler(PrintMsg);
                filer.FileApplicationWithoutRegistering();
             }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                msg = "Failed." + " " + DateTime.Now.ToString() + " " + ex.Message;
            }
            finally
            {
                //browser.Close();
            }

            return msg;
        }

        private void PrintMsg(object sender, string msg)
        {
            OnReadyToBeDisplayed(this, msg);
        }
    }
}
```

And finally the UI....

Click a button and this code runs...

```
FileApplicationTests fileApplicationPageTest = new FileApplicationTests();   
fileApplicationPageTest.OnReadyToBeDisplayed += new DisplayMessageEventHandler(WriteToLog);
fileApplicationPageTest.FileApplication();
```

And this function should update the literal:

```
private void WriteToLog(object sender, string log_entry)
    {      
            Literal1.Text += log_entry + "<br/>";
            UpdatePanel1.Update();
    }
```

Comment: You should start the long running process in a separate thread, so that the page can process and send back the content to the user, which only happens when all of your long running processes are through in your case. It really depends in this case what this long application is actually doing, you could create an ajax callback in javascript that would check the progress on a server, and start the long running process over a service call, you could create a WebSocketConnection that talks to any listeners, saying how far it is, you could split up the process in smaller processing steps...